# Correct Format of Harvest API OAuth2 Redirect URL in iOS Application

Tags: ios, url-scheme, harvest

**What is the correct format for a redirect URL when authenticating with OAuth2 and the Harvest API from an iOS application?**

[oauth.com](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/redirect-uris/redirect-uris-native-apps/) states that a redirect URL for a native application can look like `myapp://callback`. Problem is, Harvest doesn't accept such a redirect URL. It seems to require prefixing it with `http`/`https`, which causes problems when redirecting back to the iOS application at the end of the authentication flow. I don't seem to find anything relevant in the [Harvest API documentation](https://help.getharvest.com/api-v2/authentication-api/authentication/authentication/).

I have added a URL Type in Xcode where I set the `Identifier` value to `com.example.myapp` and the `URL Schemes` value to `MyApp`. No matter what redirect URL I specify (given the format mentioned above) in Harvest the authentication flow always complains that `Safari cannot open the page because the server cannot be found`. I am able to open the app manually with the `appname://` URL from the

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the URL to use regarding redirection from a web call.  I'm not certain on oath2, but on SAML it is something like

https://where you are signing in/SSOpage?RelayState=https://where you are going

I hope this helps get you to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this issue, the identifier and URL Schemes should not be `com.example.myapp` and `MyApp`, respectively. You only need to set the URL Scheme to `com.example.myapp`